# Creating a loop in python that creates lists with a name that contains a variable

Tags: python, loops, variables

I am trying to create a loop that runs 16 times, where each time through the loop the variable "x" increases by 1. Some "x"'s would be strings and some would be a portion list or variable names.

the contents of my loop is as follows

```
if ' Event Detection CH"x": Channel "x"' in df:  # Check if Data Exists in Channel
    CH"x"_n = df[' Event Detection CH"x": Channel "x"'].tolist()  # Transform Event Detection to List
    CH"x"_u = CH"x"_n.pop(0)  # Store and Remove Unit from List
    n_channels["x"] = 1  # List has been created
else:
    CH"x"_status = 'Open Channel'  # If No Data, Channel Is Open
    n_channels["x"] = 0  # No list has been created
```

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: There's no realistic (or even any) way to dynamically create named variables. Use a dictionary

Comment: Thanks. I will research what a dictionary is.